# How to calculate electronic circular dichroism (ECD) spectra from MCTDH?

Tags: spectroscopy, quantum-dynamics

Electronic circular dichroism (ECD) spectra is commonly used in organic chemistry to characterize chiral molecules. Here the question is how to simulate ECD spectra using MCTDH (Multi-configurational time-dependent Hartree)? It would be nice if the answers could provide explicit formulas.

Comment: I gave +1 a long time ago, but I came here to ask: have you figured this out yet? Any update on anything you learned about this so far, or any progress?

Comment: This reference looks like it gives the formulas for how to compute this: https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2021/cp/d1cp00822f

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually the authors of this paper are my collaborators. @Tyberius

Comment: Did you figure this out now? Did the authors (your collaborators) answer it for you?

Comment: Yes, I fully figured out this problem and the answers helps!

Comment: Very nice! Can you write a self-answer to your question here? Otherwise this takes up space in our unanswered queue. Your self-answer will also be useful for future visitors!